# cakephp get data from two tables

Tags: cakephp

I have a model class FoodItem that needs to retrieve the datas by joining tables menu_food_item. this is the code.

```
    $fooditems=$this->FoodItem->find('all',array('joins'=>array(array('table'=>'menu_food_items',
                                         'alias'=>'mfi',
                                         'type'=>'inner',
                                         'forignKey'=>false,
                                         'conditions'=>array('mfi.food_item_id=FoodItem.id','mfi.menu_id'=>$menu_id))),'fields'=>array('FoodItem.id','FoodItem.food_item_title','FoodItem.active','mfi.menu_id')));
```

i want to get menu_id with the result.(from menu_food_item table) this is the pr($fooditems); result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [FoodItem] => Array
            (
                [id] => B102
                [food_item_title] => Prown cocktail
                [active] => 1
            )

        [mfi] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 2
            )

    )

)
```

but json_encoded result shows only FoodItems table data only.no menu_food_item(mfi) data. why is that? I want to show menu_id with result

Comment: how you are encoding fooditems into json. can you put some piece of code here

Comment: $fooditems=Set::extract('/FoodItem/.', $fooditems);
  $response=array('fooditems'=>$fooditems);
  return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($response)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extracting food items here, so it will give an array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [FoodItem] => Array
            (
                [id] => B102
                [food_item_title] => Prown cocktail
                [active] => 1
            )
    )
)
```

please remove `$fooditems=Set::extract('/FoodItem/.', $fooditems);` and then try.